# Is this the correct way to sort generic type?

Tags: scala, generics

I am just trying to write a bubble sorting code using generic. I am not sure whether this is the right approach to writing sorting logic for generic. **Here "if" condition is giving compile time error**. For any particular type, this is working fine. How can I resolve this and program it in a better way? Thanks in advance.

```
def sortAny[T](list: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
var count = 0
while (count < list.length) {
  for (count <- 0 until list.length - 1) {
    if (list(count) > list(count + 1)) {
      val temp = list(count)
      list(count) = list(count + 1)
      list(count + 1) = temp
    }
  }
  count = count + 1
}

list
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a *context bound* answer for completeness. To use it, one requires a *type class* instead of a *type conversion*, that has a comparison method which takes 2 elements of type `T`.

A [*type class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) here means a module that implements a set of functions. This is a common pattern of *Ad-Hoc Polymorphism* in functional languages like Haskell, which have influenced Scala to adopt it.

The `Ordered` trait is unsuitable as a type class here, because it's comparison method takes only 1 element of type `T`. `Ordered` is meant to be mixed in and compare the `this` instance with the element `T` provided. The solution is of course to use the `Ordering` trait instead:

```
  def sortAny[T: Ordering](list: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
    var count = 0
    while (count < list.length) {
      for (count <- 0 until list.length - 1) {
        if (implicitly[Ordering[T]].gt(list(count), list(count + 1))) {
          val temp = list(count)
          list(count) = list(count + 1)
          list(count + 1) = temp
        }
      }
      count = count + 1
    }

    list
  }
```

This works both for built-in types, because Scala provides implicit orderings for them:

```
  sortAny(Array(4, 2, 5, 7, 32, 1213, 32))            // Array(2, 4, 5, 7, 32, 32, 1213)
  sortAny(Array("John", "Helen", "Merry", "Chris"))   // Array(Chris, Helen, John, Merry)
```

And for custom types too, but you'll have to either provide an implicit `Ordering` - or - mix in the `Ordered` trait in your custom type. The latter works because:

> Ordered and Ordering both provide implicits allowing them to be used
> interchangeably.

Scala will automatically create an implicit `Ordering` for your custom type, as long as it mixes in `Ordered`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortAny[T <% Ordered[T]](list: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
var count = 0
while (count < list.length) {
  for (count <- 0 until list.length - 1) {
    if (list(count) > list(count + 1)) {
      val temp = list(count)
      list(count) = list(count + 1)
      list(count + 1) = temp
    }
  }
  count = count + 1
  }

list
}
```

Output will be

```
sortAny: [T](list: Array[T])(implicit evidence$1: T => Ordered[T])Array[T]
```

T <% S (a view bound) says that type T must be convertible to S, so it has to be either a subtype of S or have implicit conversion defined.

Comment: View bounds has been deprecated. Can you modify this to an answer using context bounds?

Comment: Worked for me. I am still not clear about what this step is actually doing "T <% Ordered[T]".  Thanks for the answer @ADK

Comment: That step is inserting an implicit conversion from type T to type Ordered[T], only if type T is not a subtype of Ordered[T]. So type T becomes "viewable" as type Ordered[T]. This is necessary so that you can compare and order generic variables. In other words, it makes your generic type comparable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for this simple and clear explanation @AlinGabrielArhip